# how to write Rspec for a ruby API use Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

I recently worked on a API service, and I'm using [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) framework, but I don't quite understand how can I write rspec for my API

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Rack::Test` as described [in this blog post](http://armoredcode.com/blog/build-an-api-for-fun-with-grape/).